# Как указать в регулярке номер строки в которой искать?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно указать в регулярном выражении, что искать нужно не во всем документе, а только в пятой строке.
Например нужно число `666` заменить на `777`, но не во всем документе, а только в пятой строке, как указать в выражении что искать нужно именно в пятой строке?

Comment: Если вы используете `sed`, то указывайте номер строки в начале.

Comment: Замечательно, и что вы пробовали, что не получается?

Comment: Чисто само по себе обычное регулярное выражение не предполагает деление текста на строки. Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Если надо искать в пятой строке, то значит до нее есть 4 перевода строки, воспользуйтесь этой информацией: `(.*\n){4}...`

Comment: Андрей NOP Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо искать в пятой строке, то значит до нее есть 4 перевода строки, воспользуйтесь этой информацией: `(.*\n){4}...`